# How to reverse number orders in Excel to formate a date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm searching without success for solution to this problem, as mentioned in title.

The following:
I have many cells with numbers, like: `20170510`
This is actually a date: 10th of May 2017

Now my question, how can I bring this number in the proper form to build the right date like: `05/10/2017`? So that Excel recognizes it as a date.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your date string is in A2, then try this...

```
=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,5,2),RIGHT(A2,2))
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have spaces on the end of the number - `RIGHT(A2,2)` will take the last two digits in the cell.  If you've added an extra space at the end it will return `0 ` instead of `10` in your example.

Comment: I did make sure, but it says: "The formula you typed  contains error." A error message pops up.

Comment: @SohailAhmad you may need to use `;` instead of `,` as the delimiter.  Try changing all the `,` with `;`

Answer (score 2):

For a *column* of such numbers choose Text to Columns with Tab as delimiter and Date format YMD.

Comment: Could you tell me step by step, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler formula for you to try,

`=TEXT(TEXT(A1,"0000-00-00"),"mm/dd/yyyy")`

[image]

The advantage of this formula is, you can change the `mm/dd/yyyy` format to any other format of your choice and it would work.

`dd-mmm-yy` , `dd/mm/yyyy` etc...